# Intellij: Get rid of iml file

Tags: intellij-idea, project-structure

- A colleague has downloaded my project which I've composed using IntelliJ-2019.2
  On my machine, there is no .iml file (not in project root, nor in .idea folder).
- He opened it using IntelliJ-2018.1 and a .iml file was created in project root.
- We thought we could: Close IntelliJ-2018, uninstall, install 2019.2, delete the .iml and reopen the project with 2019.2.

However, that .iml file was created again...

Since he will be pushing to a repo, and in general because we want the whole team to work in the same way, I would like to remove this .iml, so that his project is handled by the IDE in the same way as the rest of the team.

How to "migrate" from .iml to whatever project configuration (module description) I am using (which has no .iml)?

Comment: Is it  a Gradle-built project?

Answer (score 1):

`.iml` file is a module file generated by IntelliJ idea IDE that is used for keeping module configuration.
More info: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html

For most of the people not familiar with module configuration, we don't have to worry about this file. Since it is an auto-generated file and used by Intellij Idea IDE, it is not needed for other team members.

To get rid of `my-project.iml` file I have tried 2 ways and both work:

Method 1:

- add the `.iml` file to `.gitignore` file of your project.

Method 2:

Move it to any other directory on your system.

- Move the file to any other directory (I moved it inside `.idea` directory of the project as it was added to gitignore)
- Open `module.xml` file present in your `.idea` folder of the project
- Modify this part and update the new path for the `.iml` file

```
<component name="ProjectModuleManager">
    <modules>
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/my-project.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/my-project.iml" />
    </modules>
  </component>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use git, just add *.iml to the .gitignore file in the root of the project.

checkout https://www.gitignore.io/ to create a .gitignore for you project

in your case you need at least: https://www.gitignore.io/api/intellij

Comment: Sorry Oliver, my question wasn't on how to use git in order to smudge an intelliJ project into looking like the others. It's about correcting the intelliJ project itself.

Comment: ah ok, I get it. you don't want to have iml files at all. did you just reopen the project or did you reimport the project? if not, try to reimport

Comment: I did this but still see these files in intellij

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a vite project that stopped loading when i deleted the `.iml` file, i noticed (thanks to [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73567632)) that you can simply replace:

```xml
<module fileurl="..../some.iml"></module>
```

with the contents of `some.iml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
    <modules>
      <!-- previous contents: -->
      <!--<module fileurl=""></module>-->

      <!-- replacement contents: -->
      <module type="WEB_MODULE" version="4">
        <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
          <exclude-output />
          <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$" />
          <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
          <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
        </component>
      </module>
    </modules>
  </component>
</project>
```

and the project works after using the [repair ide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/repair-ide.html) function to reopen the project.